# How to trigger Logic app in Azure dat factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app by following this article https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5893/transfer-files-from-sharepoint-to-blob-storage-with-azure-logic-apps/. I am copying multiple excel files from my SharePoint into Azure blob storage.

Now I want to trigger the logic app in my data factory. I used web activity, however, I don't what I have to give in the "body" please see below

[image]

I am new to Azure, trying to learn. Unable to find any post or article on triggering this logic app in the data factory

When I try to debug my web activity without Body I am getting this message "A valid body is required for PUT and POST requests"

Can anyone point out to be a document or advise me on the solution, please?

Comment: Do you need to supply a body?  If not, then don't.  It should still work and if it doesn't change the LogicApp to accept a GET request.

Comment: @skin I am getting this error when I debug my web activity without a body "A valid body is required for PUT and POST requests"

Comment: Yep, so change it to a GET.  The LogicApp doesn't need it but obviously ADF expects you to provide it.  You may need to flick your LogicApp to also accept a GET request by default.  OR, just put a dummy body in.

Comment: @skin When I use Get method , I am getting this error message """"   {
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"TriggerRequestMethodNotValid\",\"message\":\"The HTTP method for this request is not valid: expected 'POST' and actual 'GET'.\"}}",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Web1",
    "details": []
}"""""""""

Comment: Yeah, again, you need to change your LogicApp to accept a GET.

Comment: @Skin. It worked. I used the Post method and gave a dummy body. It is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Skin & @sthambi for sharing your valuable suggestions. Posting the same as answer to help other community members

"Use the POST method and give a dummy body - to resolve the issue"

[image]